# Pick vs PickType

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am currently learning NestJS and to that end I am making an API about "Tasks". To keep DTOs DRY I decided to create a TaskDto with all the fields returned in the Get endpoint and use Pick to create the request of the Post endpoint of my CRUD. So far I found two ways to do this with Typescript:

```
  @Post()
  createTask(@Body() request: Pick<TaskDto, 'title' | 'description'>): TaskDto {
    return this.taskService.createTask(request);
  }
```

And

```
  @Post()
  createTask(@Body() request: CreateTaskDto): TaskDto {
    return this.taskService.createTask(request);
  }
```

Where *CreateTaskDto* is:

```
import { PickType } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { TaskDto } from './task.dto';

export class CreateTaskDto extends PickType(TaskDto, [
  'title',
  'description',
]) {}
```

So I would like to know which way is better. What are the "pros" and "cons" of each approach? I am new to NestJS so I would appreciate your input on this topic.

PS: I noticed that the first approach doesn't work with swagger-ui and NestJS.

Comment: The first approach does not work because it is purely for typing purposes. It doesn't affect what actually happens at runtime. The second approach works because it affects the values at runtime (this is also why swagger-ui can properly generate docs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) here is a Typescript type helper and it changes things at the *type* level, which is great for times where you don't end up needing metadata reflection from decorators. This is because Typescript **only** reflects class types and will not reflect interface or type-level types when it comes to using the `emitDecoratorMetadata` option in your `tsconfig`, which Nest makes extensive use of.

[`PickType`](https://github.com/nestjs/mapped-types/blob/master/lib/pick-type.helper.ts) on the other hand is a mixin, a function that returns a class, and it actually has one of three places in Nest that you can import it from: `@nestjs/mapped-types` which is the base definition and modifies the `class-validator` and `class-transformer` metadata according to the passed class and parameters, `@nestjs/swagger` which extends `@nestjs/mapped-types` **and** does OpenAPI metadata modification, and `@nestjs/graphql` which extends `@nestjs/mapped-types` **and** does GraphQL metadata modification. Because these all return a class, metadata reflection still can be used and things like the `ValidationPipe` still function as expected